# Calculating a tangent intersection with R

Tags: r, plot, intersection, spline

I am trying to add a tangent to my plot at the point `x = 30` and I want to calculate the x-intersection of the tangent at `y = 0.08`.

I already found a very useful example, which I tried to use, but for some reason it is not working for `y = 0.08`. 
I don't understand the meaning of deriv in the `predict()` function nor the actual difference in between pred0 and pred1. Can someone please explain?

```
x <- seq(0,40)
y <- dnorm(seq(0,40), mean=25, sd=5)
plot(x, y)
spl <- smooth.spline(y ~ x)
lines(spl, col="green")

newx <- 30
pred0 <- predict(spl, x=newx, deriv=0)
pred1 <- predict(spl, x=newx, deriv=1)

yint <- pred0$y - (pred1$y*newx)
xint <- -yint/pred1$y
xint



plot(x, y)
abline(h=0, col="red")
lines(spl, col="red") 
points(pred0,col="red", pch=19) 
lines(x, yint + pred1$y*x) 
points(xint, 0, col="red", pch=19)
```

[image]

Comment: With `deriv=0` there is no derivative---you get the value of the spline at that point. With `deriv = 1`, you get the value of the first derivative (slope) at that point.

Comment: Generally, the `predict()` methods let you input an `x` and get a value for `y`. When you say you want a tangent line when `y = 0.8`, if you want to use `predict` your first step should be to find an `x` value corresponding to `y = 0.8`. (There might be multiple x values, or no x values, depending on the `y`).

Comment: @Gregor Thanks for pointing out what derivative actually meant. I still don't know how to address the problem in practical terms. How can I find the x value corresponding to y = 0.08 hence I am trying to find that out using predict. Sry, I am a little confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you have no problem calculating the tangent line and the intersect, but rather need some help in finding the `x` value for a given `y` value. This method will work for any smooth curve, but mark Gregors warning. There might not be a corresponding x value, or there might be several.

```
x <- seq(0, 40, by=0.01)
y <- dnorm(x, mean=25, sd=5)
spl <- smooth.spline(y ~ x)
plot(spl, type="l")

yval <- 0.08
ad <- abs(yval - spl$y)

if (min(ad) > max(diff(spl$y))*10) {
    warning("The supplied y value is out of bounds")
}

xval <- x[which(diff(sign(diff(ad))) > 1) + 1]
points(xval, rep(yval, length(xval)))
```

With that `xval` you can calculate the tangent as you've already done.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. but for some reason it seems like I am still doing sth wrong. my calculated x value output is numeric(0).

Comment: Did you notice that the `x` in `x[which(diff(sign(diff(ad))) > 1) + 1]` is the same `x` as in the first line? The code actually finds an index, and then returns the value of `x` there. Other than that, inspect the result line by line, where does things go wrong?

Comment: Ah, sorry. it worked. it was just a silly mistake :) Very thanks! you all helped me a lot :)